# Okay, still having trouble with else if method in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SherlockHolmes {
  String answer = "Watson";
  String response = " ";
  int tries = 0;
  int tries = 3;

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); {
    System.out.print("Enter the name of Sherlock's partner, and dear            friend.");
    response = input.nextLine();
    tries++;

    if (response.equals("Watson"))
    else
      while (tries <= 3)
        System.out.print("Ooooh, sorry kid! Try again!"); {
      System.out.println("Yes, that's right, Barrel Rider.");
      break;
    } else if (tries == 3) {
      System.out.println("Ooooo, sorry kid. But, it looks like you're S.O.L!");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

My biggest question is why I'm getting two errors with this method, the error

```
being: SherlockHolmes.java:16: error: 'else' without 'if'
   
   else 
      ^

SherlockHolmes.java:24: error: 'else' without 'if'
 
     else if(tries == 3)
      ^
2 errors
```

I put if code in every line, yet its telling me : "Else without if" for both entries of "else". I am kind of frustrated, and I don't slagging get how Java thinks I have no if when it is clearly there!

What am I doing wrong that Java thinks I have no if code fashioned in?

Comment: It is a best practice in Java coding to *always* use `{}` brackets for an `if` or an `else` block.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to start using braces around your branch bodies, and get an IDE to format your code - then you'll be able to see why your current code is invalid.

Comment: while not strictly necessary, I would advise you to **always** follow up an `if` or `else` with a block of `{}`. This can help avoid a lot of problems (along with the ones you are currently having and some less obvious ones) later.

Comment: Actually the biggest question is: why don't you start with the basics. As in: put your code into a method. It is possible to put to simply put a `{ }` block into your class directly (this is called a "initializer block"); but for a newbie; most likely that is not what you want. Instead; you want to study how Java classes should be structured in general. (hint: add a main-method). Then start writing few lines of code. When you think "this looks ok; it should compile"; then run the compiler. Repeat. Instead of writing 20, 30 lines of code ... and then trying to isolate the syntax errors within.

Comment: @Jägermeister : Dude, I Am learning the basics. This is code from a class on Udemy.com, I followed the code to the letter, and then found all of these errors still.  So, I made edits. But, I ended up with errors still.

Comment: We can avoid braces if you want to write underneath logic in a single line or same line, however as a best practice in Java coding to always use {} brackets for an if or an else block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `if` statement with an empty body, you NEED curly braces in Java. Honestly, you should just have way more braces in your code. I strongly suggest reading up on Java coding conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Example:

```
if (response.equals("Watson"))

else while (tries <= 3)
```

For that empty `if` to compile, you need:

```
if (response.equals("Watson")) {
}
else while (tries <= 3) {
    // loop body
}
```

Comment: It's not the amount of braces, but the positioning of the braces.

Answer (score 0):

You have many syntax errors.

First, you cannot attach an **else-if** to a **while** block. Second, if you're trying to make it so that if the response does *not* equal "Watson", then use the "not equal to" operator, which is simply "**!**" (an exclamation mark).

Answer (score 0):

Control flow is made up of

`if (condition) {}` Must be used once, and must be first

`else if (condition) {}` as many times as you want, optional, must be in between `else` and `if` if included

`else {}` optional, must be last and used once if included

Curly braces and order are **mandatory**. In Java, it is best practice, and usually required to put curly braces around all blocks: `if`, `while`, `for`. Another thing you need to know is that *while loops are not the same as conditionals.* They can't be attached to `else` or `else if` statements. So your while loop needs to change to

```
while (tries <= 3) {
   ...
}
```

Do this similarly with the conditional statements.

```
    System.out.print("Enter the name of Sherlock's partner, and dear            friend.");
    response = input.nextLine();
    tries++;
    while (tries <= 3) {
         if (response.equals("Watson")) {
             System.out.println("Yes, that's right, Barrel Rider.");
         }
         else { 
             System.out.print("Ooooh, sorry kid! Try again!"); 
             break;
         }

    if (tries == 3) { // If the while loop finishes
        System.out.println("Ooooo, sorry kid. But, it looks like you're S.O.L!");
        break;
    }
```